# How to copy and paste Xib file with xCode Interface Builder

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xib

I need to create a new xib file and want to use an existing xib to base my layout off of. What's the best way to create the new xib file? If it was Android I'd copy and paste the xml and then start tweaking but with the IB I don't have that option (right?).

I've tried two things so far, (1) copying and pasting the file in xCode but the option isn't there and (2) copying all the UI elements from the old xib and pasting them into a new blank xib. This copies all the UI objects, but doesn't maintain structure or spacing at all. What's the best way?

Comment: why making a copy of xib file and adding it to Xcode too is not working for you?

Comment: Outside of xCode? I suppose I could do that. Seems unnecessary.

Comment: Okay that works for me. The problem is the xib file still references the old view controller. How can I change it to reference a newly created view controller?

Comment: @Kyle Open it in IB, click File Owner, select the Identity Inspector pane on the right, and change the Class field to your new view controller.

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed. Squatch or @Denis - Care to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just make a copy of NIB file, rename it and add to the same Xcode project. Change File Owner class in new nib if needed.

Comment: I wish i could give you more points, you saved me so much time

Answer (score 6):

When I need to do this I convert the file to a .nib (shift click the file and delete .xib and add .nib) then you can see all the XML copy that.  Then I make a new .xib and convert that to .nib and paste the XML then you can convert them both back to a .xib.  You can also Right click the file and navigate to View As > Source Code

Answer (score 1):

If Storyboard is used: Add a new UIViewController to the storyboard. Remove its main view so that the view controller is empty. Set the Class of the view controller (in the Identity Inspector) to that of your nib's File's Owner. Also make sure the .h and .m files are added to your project already.

Now open the nib, select the top-most view and press Cmd-C to copy it to the clipboard. Switch to the storyboard, select that new, empty view controller. Press Cmd-V to paste the contents of the nib into this view controller.

You may have to reconnect all the outlets and actions, but at least you don't have to do the layout again.